# Explain forbidden inheritance across the domain dimensions of representation/implementation vs semantics

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance

I am going through this nice [write up on thoughtworks about inheritance vs composition](https://www.thoughtworks.com/en-us/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose). I understood the authors explanation of the dual purpose of inheritance. But, I am confused on the specific details about "dimensions".

> When you have a situation where either composition or inheritance will
> work, consider splitting the design discussion in two: 1)  The
> representation/implementation of your domain concepts is one dimension
> 2) The semantics of your domain concepts and their relationship to one
> another is a second dimension.

> In general, inheriting within one of
> these dimensions is fine. The problem becomes when we forget to
> separate the two dimensions, and start inheriting across
> inter-dimensional boundaries.

Can anyone explain the significant difference between these two "dimension" concepts?

What is confusing me:

> "Implementation of your domain concepts".

How this is different from "semantics"? Usually when we apply inheritance, we identify the "domain classes (in Author words, concept class) and establish the relationship (Implementation) isn't it?

Comment: I think this is a good question. Based on the citations I also think this particular author is a horrible educator. I fully understand the concepts of inheritance and composition as well as the benefits and downsides of each. Yet I do not understand what he is on about. I suggest you try a different source on the topic.

Comment: @GregBurghardt this is NOT about "dimension", it is about "Software development" AND "design". "Domain" is common concept in software design/development. What I am trying to understand is, how these "dimension" in perspective of s/w impacts inheritence.

Comment: @kosa:  consider to edit your questions so it becomes more clear what you already understood and where you got lost. Just saying "this is not about the english meaning of dimensions" is still not explaining with what you are struggling precisely, Don't try to fix this hastily, you have time enough to choose your words more careful. Thanks.

Comment: @DocBrown Sorry added that comment to "undelete". Updated the question with more details, hope it is clear now.

Comment: @MartinMaat Would you be able to share few resources which helped in understanding these concepts in simple terms? I feel the Thoughtworks author complicated the write up bringing in "domain concepts" OR not properly defining what "domain concepts" means.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. The edit helps a lot. I was misunderstanding the premise of the question.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question, but I still find it hard to answer. The author's definition of "representation/implementation" and "semantics" as it relates to object-oriented concepts is the key to answering this question, but unfortunately we can only infer what those meanings are. These terms do not have universal, agreed-upon meanings in software engineering. At least none that I can connect to the original blog post.

Comment: @kosa There's a search text box at the top of this page.Try "composition inheritance".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got this correctly, there are already examples in the blog post which show what the author means. Take the domain class `CustomerGroup`. When we set our point of view on how to implement such a class, it could be derived from `ArrayList<Customer>`. However, when we put the focus on domain modeling ("semantics"), a `CustomerGroup` is-a `DemographicSegment`, hence it could also inherit that class. One could be tempted to use multiple inheritance here, or (in languages like Java or C#), single inheritance plus interface inheritance. From my own experience, I agree with Steven Lowe that this is usually not a good idea and will sooner or later cause trouble.

Hence, the author is recommending to resolve such design problems by separating the "implementation dimension" from the "semantical dimension". A `CustomerGroup` can be represented by `ArrayList<Customer>`, using a member variable of that type ("composition over inheritance"). That will allow `CustomerGroup` to be a child class of `DemographicSegment`, so there is only one kind of inheritance left. If you are still inclined to make a derivation from `ArrayList<Customer>` (maybe you want to override some technical methods for debugging, hashing or whatever), an alternative could be to introduce an utility class, lets call it `ListOfCustomers` which derives `ArrayList<Customer>` and exists purely for the sake of implementation. Then `CustomerGroup` can be implemented by making use of `ListOfCustomers` (by composition, of course).

Answer (score -1):

Consider Java's `Map`, `TreeMap` and `HashMap`.

The semantics includes "unique keys associated with (non-unique) values", and the representation includes "tree-structure vs hash-structure".

Comment: I am sorry Caleth, your answer is as confusing as the Author. Would be able to add more details?